Отслеживание запросов Wireshark (HTTPS)?
Недавно столкнулся с тем, что HTTPS-трафик нормально не фильтруется. Для этого требуется выгружать TLS ключи шифрования и заниматься танцами с бубном. Плюс существует проблема, что если используется не Google Chrome / Mozilla Firefox / Opera или другие известные браузеры/программы, что позволяют это сделать, то проводить анализ пакетов будет либо невозможно, либо крайне трудно.
Существует ли какое-то расширение для Wireshark / возможность установить сертификат (как у Fiddler; чтобы дать больше прав для приложения), чтобы мониторить HTTPS-трафик в реальном времени?

Как вариант попробуйте посмотреть в сторону Charles, необходимо установить сертификат в OC для его работы. Насколько помню, шарку тоже нужны сертификаты для просмотра защищенных запросов, но с ним опыта меньше.

@MoloF Благодарю, но мне интересен именно Wireshark. Ну или на крайний случай любое другое свободное ПО. Посмотрел Charles. К сожалению, он проприетарный.

Попробуйте найти ключ лицензии в свободном доступе для чарли, можно найти в течении одной минуты и работать спокойно без проблем.
